# Is there any way to check which kind of RAM my computer uses without opening it up?

Tags: memory, windows-xp, hardware, system-information

I would like to check which type of RAM my computer uses before I order an upgrade. I'm fairly sure its DDR2 but I would like to double check this.

Is there any way to check this in Windows XP without opening the case up and looking?

*EDIT* 
The content police seem to have gotten the wrong end of the stick, I was looking for a piece of software or a command that would allow me to check this. I feel that this makes this question perfectly valid for StackOverflow and of interest to other programmers.

Comment: And you want to do this programmatically ... right?

Comment: That's implied. If I ask how to flip flapjacks, I want the answer in C.

Comment: Hmmm, no still not programming related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) can tell you. On the SPD tab you can view the DIMM specific information

Comment: thanks - cpu-z says its DDR...turns out my intuition was wrong! good thing I checked :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a standard, vanilla box, then head over to Crucial and use their memory selector tool.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**wmic memorychip list full**

In this you will get memorytype if it is 24 then you are using DDR3  and if it is 0 then there are chances that you are using DDR4

Ansh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Find out the motherboard/chipset from the device manager, google it, know what it takes.

As Greg Hewgill says, you'd need to script that some how (to make this a valid question on SO) - but you'd have to do that part yourself =)

Answer (score 0):

CPU-Z Can tell you the type as well as the current clock speed and memory timings.

http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it helps:
Taskmanager > Performance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case CPUID not showing RAM details use HWiNFO, it will provide deep details about Hardware
https://www.hwinfo.com/download/